# Ternary operator - exercise. I didn't get it, how the counting mechanics works - detailed explanation needed

Tags: conditional-operator

Thank you in advance for your time and help.
Exercise:
Write the code for sumDigitsInNumber(int number). The method takes a three-digit whole number. You need to calculate the sum of the digits of this number, and then return the result.

Consider this example:
The sumDigitsInNumber method is called with argument 546.

Example output:
15

CODE:

```
   public class Solution {
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   System.out.println(sumDigitsInNumber(546));
   }

   public static int sumDigitsInNumber(int number) {

   return number ==0? 0:number%10+sumDigitsInNumber(number/10);
   }
  }
```

This is a solution and the task has been passed. The problem is the solution had been implemented by someone (not by me) therefore I can't understand How this function does its job.

I tried to test the function parts separately, just to see what would happen, and here is the result:

```
number%10 = 546%10;
546/10 = 54;
```

output:

```
6+sumDigitsInNumber(546/10) - which is totally wrong.
```

I don't understand HOW sumDigitsInNumber is treated by the ternary operator in there and how this short line of code:

```
return number ==0? 0:number%10+sumDigitsInNumber(number/10);
```

makes such a complicated calculation?

Can anyone explain it to me in a way it would have explained to a Java-child?
TYVM in advance.

Comment: `6+sumDigitsInNumber(546/10) - which is totally wrong.` Why is this wrong?

Comment: it gives a rather different outcome than it's expected, meaning it doesn't count the sum of digits of (int number).

Comment: But it does. Its recursive.

Comment: Although It does within the full-written function, it doesn't if you gonna separate them in a way I did it above. I separated the function in two parts just to understand it better and in detail, now I'm pretty sure I separated them in the wrong way and maybe I should close the question as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

So, using the example number of 546, let's step through the code.

In the first run, it does indeed return `6+sumDigitsInNumber(546/10)`, that is all correct.

Because `sumDigitsInNumber`'s parameter (number) is int, the decimal portion of the division is truncated, resulting in essentially a floor operation (forced round down). And we recursively call `sumDigitsInNumber`'s, so we just keep "looping" that section of code. So for the second run, it is equivalent to `sumDigitsInNumber(54)`, plus the additional 6 from the first run (`6+sumDigitsInNumber(54)`).

The second call returns `4+sumDigitsInNumber(54/10)` by following the same logic as the first call. This is equivalent to `4+sumDigitsInNumber(5)`.

Then we run the whole process again, which returns `5+sumDigitsInNumber(5/10)`, equivalent to `5+sumDigitsInNumber(0)`.

The final call, `sumDigitsInNumber(0)`, will return 0 because of the ternary operator in the return statement.

To expand this all out:

```
sumDigitsInNumber(546)
= 6+sumDigitsInNumber(546/10) = 6+sumDigitsInNumber(54)
= 6+(4+sumDigitsInNumber(54/10)) = 6+(4+sumDigitsInNumber(5))
= 6+(4+(5+sumDigitsInNumber(5/10))) = 6+(4+(5+sumDigitsInNumber(0)))
= 6+(4+(5+0))
= 6+(4+(5))
= 6+(9)
= 15
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys, that was exactly what I needed! Very helpful!